# Can I have some constant part of the page in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Can I have some constant part of the page in AngularJS, like logo, side menu, breadcrumb?

The question is how to have any part constant and navigate only content part?

Is the only way is to include html fragments?

Comment: use angular route segment

Comment: You mean this http://angular-route-segment.com/?

Comment: check my answer below. it has code from that website it self

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body ng-app="">
  <div>
    <p>CONSTANT PART</p>
  </div>
  <div ui-view>
    content use ui router for changing content configure routes in app.js
  </div>
</body>
</html
```

use ui-router the content in ui-view changes according to the state

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: UI-Router implements its own URL routing mechanics with its own "state" concept on top of it. angular-route-segment doesn't try to replace something in AngularJS. It is based on built-in $route engine, so that it tries to extend it rather than to replace.

Answer (score 0):

[Angular Route Segment](http://angular-route-segment.com/)

```
bower install angular-route-segment
```

The library provides two pieces of code: $routeSegment service and app-view-segment directive. Both are placed in their own modules which you must include as dependencies in your app module:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'route-segment', 'view-segment']);

$routeSegmentProvider.segment('s1', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/section1.html',
    controller: MainCtrl});

$routeSegmentProvider.within('s1').segment('home', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/section1/home.html'});

$routeSegmentProvider.within('s1').segment('itemInfo', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/section1/item.html',
    controller: Section1ItemCtrl,
    dependencies: ['id']});

$routeSegmentProvider.within('s1').within('itemInfo').segment('overview', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/section1/item/overview.html'});
```

Then, any app-view-segment tags (which are similar to built-in ng-view) in the DOM will be populated with the corresponding route segment item. You must provide a segment index as an argument to this directive to make it aware about which segment level in the tree it should be linked to.

index.html:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-class="{active: $routeSegment.startsWith('s1')}">
        <a href="/section1">Section 1</a>
    </li>
    <li ng-class="{active: $routeSegment.startsWith('s2')}">
        <a href="/section2">Section 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="contents" app-view-segment="0"></div>
```

Where ul code is static and will be displayed on every page